# Saving an Access table as dBASE_IV file (.dbf) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dbf

I am making a small application that will read .csv files into a newly generated access table (generated with vb.net), I am filling this database with sql and now I would like to output that table as a .dbf file!

I can't find any info on this subject.

I know some of you will tell me to just make the script in vba in access, but there are some functions that require me to use vb.net and the client wants a single .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a forum post [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/dc1ba303-b887-4d2b-91e5-f53351164be8/) that includes some VB.NET sample code to create a .dbf file and write some data into it. The code uses the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB) which is no longer distributed with Windows by default, but can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).